# In SQL Server, how do I reset the id column of my table back to 1?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, identity

My table has an int-based identity column in SQL Server.

Since I have removed entries from this table, the id's no longer begin at 1.

How do I reset the id column of my table back to 1?

Comment: You can follow this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023574/reordering-identity-primary-key-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reordering Identity primary key in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023574/reordering-identity-primary-key-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a bug but a feature of SQL server 2012. This happens when ever you restart the SQL instance.

The jumping value depends on the datatype, for `int` it's `1000` and for `bigint` its `10,000`. (this is the cache allocated for `identity` which is lost on restarting of instance)

Please refer this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-2012-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is) for a preferred solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove ALL entries from a table AND have the identity reset to 1 (or whatever its initial seed value is) you can do so with a TRUNCATE TABLE command instead of DELETE.