# How to reset auto increment after delete using code first?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-web-api, crud

I want to reset my auto incremented value after I use delete, If I use post after using delete the value will increment and not fill the previously existing ID, for instance if I delete ID 5 and use post to create then ID 5 will be skipped over and ID 6 will be created. I am using code first approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset AutoIncrement in SQL Server after Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510121/reset-autoincrement-in-sql-server-after-delete)

Comment: Read the following. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43910/reset-identity-value This is actually something that you cannot do and it is also strongly advised not to do

Comment: That's the correct and logical behaviour. Nothing is skipped. Do you *really* want to associate a **new** record with any related table entries that have the *old* ID? What you want to implement is a serious bug

Comment: @PeterB when someone asks how to shoot himself in the foot it's best to add a warning before linking to instructions

Comment: From Chirag Bansal: *Please can you be more specific about the database. Also as I know in MySQL, the auto increment counter arranges itself.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reordering Identity primary key in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023574/reordering-identity-primary-key-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches - You can re-seed the Identity property after your Delete:

EG

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Person.AddressType', RESEED, 10);  
GO
```

OR (if you are deleting all rows)

You Can simply TRUNCATE the table. (assuming there are no FKs)

First option require dbo - 2nd option requires Alter Table